# how to use session/cookie in twisted.web?

Tags: python, twisted

I am implementing an http server with twisted.web.  Here comes the problem: there is a login operation; after that, I want the http server to remember each client using acookie/session, until the user closes the browser.

I've read the twisted.web document, but I can't figure out how to do this.  I know the request object has a function named getSession(), then a session object will be returned. What next?  How do I store the information during the several requests?

I also searched the twisted mail list; there nothing very helpful, and I am still confused.  If someone used this before, please explain this to me, or even put some code here, so I can understand it myself. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You can use "request.getSession()" to get a componentized object.

You can read more about componentized in http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.python.components.Componentized.html -- the basic way of using it is via defining an interface and an implementation, and pushing your on objects into the session.

Comment: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.python.components.Componentized.html is an updated link

Answer (score 4):

Calling getSession() will generate a session and add the cookie to the request:

[getSession() source code](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/src/twisted/web/server.py#L494)

If the clients already has a session cookie then calling getSession() will read it and return a Session with the original Session content.  So it is transparent to your code whether or not it is actually creating the Session cookie or just reading it.

Session cookies have certain properties... if you want more control over the contents of the cookie then look at Request.addCookie() which getSession() calls behind the scenese.

Answer (score 3):

See this related question [Store an instance of a connection - twisted.web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936994/store-an-instance-of-a-connection-twisted-web). The answer there links to this blog post http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/53680.html, which shows an example of storing a counter for the number of visits for the session (thanks to jcalderone for the example):

```
# in a .rpy file launched with `twistd -n web --path .`
cache()

from zope.interface import Interface, Attribute, implements
from twisted.python.components import registerAdapter
from twisted.web.server import Session
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

class ICounter(Interface):
    value = Attribute("An int value which counts up once per page view.")

class Counter(object):
    implements(ICounter)
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.value = 0

registerAdapter(Counter, Session, ICounter)

class CounterResource(Resource):
    def render_GET(self, request):
        session = request.getSession()
        counter = ICounter(session)   
        counter.value += 1
        return "Visit #%d for you!" % (counter.value,)

resource = CounterResource()
```

Don't worry if this seems confusing - there are two things that you need to understand before the behaviour here makes sense:

1. [Twisted (Zope) Interfaces & Adapters](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/components.html)
2. [Componentized](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.python.components.Componentized.html)

The counter value is stored in an Adapter class, the Interface class documents what that class provides. The reason that you can store persistent data in the Adapter is because Session (returned by getSession()) is a subclass of Componentized.

Comment: FYI: The "value" attribute in the above code can be anything. It can be a whole dictionary, if you like. That wasn't entirely obvious from the twisted documentation, but it works fine.

Comment: I just want to rant about this somewhere. This is honestly the worst session storage code I have ever seen from any framework that does something like that. I shouldn't have to define 2 classes or adapt anything just to store a simple value in a session. This is a pretty infuriatingly badly designed API in Twisted.